# No suitable driver found for jdbc Neo4j

Tags: java, jdbc, neo4j

I already checked the other question about my issue, but none of them solved.
I imported the Neo4j Jar by configuring the build path, but still I get this error.

```js
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class TestNeo4j {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
  
  
  Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j://localhost:7474/", "neo4j", "neo4j");
  Statement st = c.createStatement();
  String cql = "match (m)-[:IS_ALLERGIC_TO]->(n:Product) where n.name = 'gluten' return m.name";
  ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(cql);
  while(rs.next())
   System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
  
  c.close();
 
 
 }

}
```

This is my code. Can you figure out what the problem is?

Comment: make sure you get the full jar, with dependencies: http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-jdbc/2.1.4/

Comment: thank you so much, it was the jar without dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/developer-resources/issues/36), use neo4j jar **with dependencies** (neo4j-jdbc-2.1.4-jar-**with-dependencies**.jar).

You can grab it from neo4j release repository, [here](http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases/org/neo4j/neo4j-jdbc/2.1.4/)

Comment: I've added the dependencies too, but still not working